# Three.js Black Video CORS issue?

Tags: three.js, cross-domain, webgl

I have a long term ongoing problem of sometimes getting black video, with sound in a Three.js texture on mobile and sometimes desktop.

I've been around the houses trying to solve it, and this is what I have so far:

```
if(!video || video == null){
    video = document.createElement( 'video' );
    source = document.createElement('source');

    video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'true');
    source.setAttribute('type',"video/mp4");
}


if(isIOS() || isIE11())
  source.setAttribute('src',"http://" + document.domain + "/cdn/" + sceneObject.video);
    else
 source.setAttribute('src',cdnPrefix + "/" + sceneObject.video);

video.appendChild(source);
video.load();



(function () {

    THREE.noVideoTextureSupport = isIE11();


    THREE.VideoTexture = (function () {
        var _videoTexture = THREE.VideoTexture;
        var _ieVideoTexture = function ( video, mapping, wrapS, wrapT, magFilter, minFilter, format, type, anisotropy ) {
            if (THREE.noVideoTextureSupport) {
                var scope = this;

                scope.video = video;
                scope.ctx2d = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
                var canvas = scope.ctx2d.canvas;
                canvas.width = 2048;
                canvas.height = 1024;

                scope.ctx2d.drawImage(scope.video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                THREE.Texture.call( scope, scope.ctx2d.canvas, mapping, wrapS, wrapT, magFilter, minFilter, format, type, anisotropy );

                scope.generateMipmaps = false;

                function update() {
                    requestAnimationFrame( update );
                    if ( video.readyState >= video.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA ) {
                        scope.ctx2d.drawImage(scope.video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        scope.needsUpdate = true;
                    }
                }

                update();
            }
        };
        return (THREE.noVideoTextureSupport ? _ieVideoTexture : _videoTexture);
    })();

    THREE.VideoTexture.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Texture.prototype );
    THREE.VideoTexture.prototype.constructor = THREE.VideoTexture;

})();



if(!isMobile)
    panoVideoPlay();
else if(!firstPlay)
    panoVideoPlay();
else{

    $('body').append('<div id="play-button" class="playButton"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>');
    $('#preloaderItems').remove();


    window.addEventListener('touchstart', function videoStart() {
        panoVideoPlay();
        $("body").scrollTop(1);
        $('#preloader').remove();
        if(firstPlay){
            $("#play-button").remove();
            firstPlay = false;
            showLoader();
        }

        this.removeEventListener('touchstart', videoStart);
    });
  }


 }

 function panoVideoPlay(){
   makeVideoPlayableInline(video);
   video.play();
  checkPlayBack();
 }



var checkPlayBack = function(event){
   console.log("panoVideo.checkPlayBack()");
   var panoPlayBackInterval = setInterval(function(){

     if (video.currentTime > 0 || video.readyState > 0){
       clearInterval(panoPlayBackInterval);
         hideLoader();
         showVideo(video);
     }
  },10);
 }

  function showVideo(video){
console.log("panoVideo.showVideo()");
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );

texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );

panoVideoMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
panoVideoMesh.scale.x = -1;
panoVideoMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;


loadScene();
scene.remove(box);
scene.add(panoVideoMesh);
addLights();
}
```

The video is encoded as such in FFMPEG

> out.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline  -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5000k -bufsize 2200k -s 1920:1080 -threads 0 -b:a 128k -movflags faststart out2K.mp4

As you can see, I've run into countless problems on IE and iOS, so I've done a nasty hack on IE which I found on the Three.js forums, and for iOS and IE I proxy the files through the server from the CDN to get around the countless security issues I was facing.

Chrome is usually fine (but I've had reports of Black screen with sound on Chrome on Android on a Samsung S5), however on the Android Note 3  I have here I'm having the same issue in the Android Stock Browser.

Usually when it goes wrong there is a usually an unidentified Script error on every render. Hard to debug on iOS and Android Stock Browser without Chrome:inspect!

On the Android stock browser if I use the CDN I get black video, sound and lots of errors - if I use the proxy files I get black screen and nothing loading..

I'm using Amazon EC2 as the Server and CloudFront for distribution, where I've had cross domain issues I've had to resort to a Apache Proxy to serve the files via the EC2 server.

I've done everything I can think of to get Cross Domain to work,

S3 has the following CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

CloudFront has the forward headers behaviours set with Origin, Access Control Headers & Method etc.

I've set Mod_Headers on the server .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://cdn.example.com"
</IfModule>
```

When I CURL the files from the host it seems OK

i.e.

> curl -I -H "Origin: http://example.com" http://cdn.example.com/videofile.mp4

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 38150681
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2016 20:55:25 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 02:45:32 GMT
ETag: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
x-amz-meta-md5-hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin
Age: 1094
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But when I try the other way

> curl -I -H "Origin: http://cdn.example.com/videoFile.mp4" http://example.com/file/from/java/server

I get

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Request method 'HEAD' not supported
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2016 21:15:05 GMT
Server: Jetty(8.0.4.v20111024)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://cdn.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Allow: GET
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 1431
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
```

I'm not sure if that **Request method 'HEAD' not supported** is going to be an issue.

I've spent A LOT of time on this, and I seem to be getting somewhere but just now can't see what to try next.

If anyone can help me I'd super appreciate it!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Ha yea I'm not sure I can remember how. I'll have a look through my code. I recall it might have been adding something to .htaccess and Apache settings for iOS and IE when the file gets proxied through the server. Where are you having a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the `video` element worked for me.

For example:

```html
<video src="https://video.url" loop muted playsinline crossorigin="anonymous" />
```